# Efficiently iterating through a map while inserting on other thread

Tags: c++, data-structures, thread-safety

I have an `std::map < std::string, std::string >`  which is having values added to it at irregular intervals from one thread (but frequently and needs to be very fast), and occasionally having groups of entries removed.

I need from a different thread to dump a snapshot of the map as text to a debug log on command from a user.

Clearly it's not thread safe to just iterate through the map outputting the debug information while it could be updated so I'm currently taking a read lock (mutex) before dumping the data and a write lock for every insert or delete. This works fine, but I can't really lock the map for this long, it delays the processing of incoming updates too much.

I don't believe I can lock and unlock the debug dump thread for each item as modifying the map from the other thread can invalidate the iterator I believe.

Is there any way I can do this safely without having to take out a read lock on the whole data structure while I write it out so that new values can still be inserted quickly? I realise I won't be able to get a guarenteed consistent view of the data if values can be added and removed while I'm iterating though it, but as long as it's safe that's understood.

If there is no way to use a map for this, can anyone suggest any other data structure I could use?

edit: I'm hoping for a solution that means I don't need to take out an expensive lock when adding an item.

Comment: I should add that I can't use c++11 at this time.

Comment: How big is your `map`?  Locking it for the duration of the I/O may be expensive, but you could make a copy of the map (quicker than writing it to disk) and perform the I/O from the copy.  This guarantees that the output will reflect the state of the map at a specific moment in time.

Comment: A hundred or so entries normally but can be several hundred or more sometimes,

Comment: With that few entries (we usually deal with cache structures in the thousands) I would expect the copy to be efficient enough to work for you.  I'd suggest trying that and profiling to see if it causes you performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, my intuition was that that would be too slow, but of course I need to measure it, Thansk :) I've added an update to the question. I'm also keen to avoid a write lock for each update. I'm not sure that's easy to avoid of course which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 solutions I can see at this moment:

1. (Easy, but might still take too long): copy the map (or assign to another container) while locked and then dump the local copy to the debug log while not locked
2. (Some more work): delegate the updates of the map to another thread via a queue.  If the other thread is the one that dumps to the debug log, then you don't need the locks anymore.  This way the fast threads are only locked while accessing the queue.

Comment: oooh solution two might work, it's important that these map updates don't hold up the main thread for long, but dont need to be done quickly.